# Ultrasphinx Error after installation Gitorious

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, gitorious, ultrasphinx

I installed Gitorious on my server Linux. I login with my admin user. I uploaded my public ssh key on Gitorious. 
Now, I would like create a new project, but when I create a new project I have this error on my log

> `** ultrasphinx: spelling support not available (raspell configuration raised "uninitialized constant Ultrasphinx::Spell::Aspell")`

I execute this command, but it's not a solution...

> $ aptitude install libaspell-dev
>
> $ gem install raspell

If you want you can read that http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/gitorious-spelling-problems.htm. It's a website talking about this error

If anyone can help me I would be very happy, because its been a while since I seek a solution to this error.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question. I'd better install gitolite if I were in your situation. Gitolite offers more functionalities and pretty easy to setup and manage.

Comment: Is your raspell installation working? Ie is the little ruby script mentioned at https://github.com/evan/raspell produces the right output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't resolved this, but I have installed Gitlab and now Gitlab is perfect for me.